# How to access/edit sharepoint 2010 status feed (what's happening) from APIs

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm having a tough time find the correct web service or client object model for accessing the status feed for a user.  I need to access the latest update and have the ability to update it.

Also, if editing the status, how will I determine if the current user is authorized to make that edit?

Thanks for any info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found this class reference.  That should do the trick:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559383.aspx